# ArcGIS Server 'An invalid where clause' error even tough the where clause is valid SQL

Tags: rest, esri, arcgis-server

We have ArcGIS Server (AGS) running with 2 nodes.  When I query the map service layer, using a simple True statement such as 1=1, on ONLY on one of the nodes, it returns a SEVERE error stating "An invalid where clause or definition expression has been requested: "1=1".  The other node returns valid results.  The service is configured with "**Use Standardized Queries:** true"; also, if that was an issue, both nodes would be throwing the same error.

I would expect both server nodes to behave the same way